# PHP Sudo permissions only works for 'ALL' commands when using exec()

Tags: php, debian, sudo, sudoers

I need my PHP code to run scripts as a different user with exec(), and so in the sudoers file I added: `www-data ALL=(csgo) NOPASSWD: WWW_COMMANDS` where WWW_COMMANDS is an alias list of the scripts i need to run. While this works fine when I use `su -s /bin/bash www-data` to log in as php and test if it works through ssh, when I try to actually send the command on my site with `exec("sudo -u csgo sh /path/to/script.sh")` and print the output it tells me `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` and the script will not have run. I also added `Defaults:www-data !requiretty` to my sudoers file to no effect. The only way I can get it to work when running the exec() on my page is to set `www-data ALL=(csgo) NOPASSWD: ALL`, which obviously isn't a great solution. Anyone know why this is happening / how to fix it.

Comment: You dont show us the WWW_COMMANDS list, but I notice you use `sh` in the sudo. Try removing it if it is not in your command list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't even know a script would run without a . or a sh. meuh's comment worked, removing the sh before the command fixed the issue.